# MKPointAnnotation go to another view

Tags: swift, mkmapview, ios10

I would like to know how can I go to another view when I tap title on 
MKPointAnnotation

```
func addPin(lat:Double, lng:Double) {
        let testPin = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
        dropPin.coordinate = testPin
        dropPin.title = "123456"
        mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
    }
```

I need to segue with identifier "More"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this delegate method in your code and check it

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView){
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "PlaceDetail", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Worked, but when I press it give me black screen :(

Comment: please modified performSegue() method with your identifier

Comment: When I connect "moreViewController" to view it give me black screen, when I disconnect it work. How can I repair it?

Comment: please check you identifier name is correct as you wrote in performSegue()

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this method from **MKMapViewDelegate**:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "PlaceDetail", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this delegate method is only called if OP has set `rightCalloutAccessoryView` with `annotationView`.

Comment: When I connect "moreViewController" to view it give me black screen, when I disconnect it work. How can I repair it?

Comment: To less information to understand your problem. Do you use storyboard?